# Porque no se cumplen las condiciones?

Tags: java

cuando inicio este programa, por ejemplo pongo valor 11 no me entra en el condicional `if ((valor >10)&&(valor <20))` , ¿por qué puede ser?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author carlos
 */
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UsoCondiciones {
    public static void main (String[]args){

    Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int valor =0;
   valor = Scan.nextInt();

    if((valor >0)&&(valor<10)){

    Scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Valor del 1 al 9");
    if ((valor >10)&&(valor <20)){
              System.out.println("Valor del 10 al 19");


 if ((valor >= 20)&&(valor<30)){
              System.out.println("Valor del 20 al 29");

  }
    }else{
    System.out.println("Incorrcete");


}
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

porque tienes los if anidados, entonces si ya no entra en el primer if se salta los demás:

```
Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int valor =0;
   valor = Scan.nextInt();

    if((valor >0)&&(valor<10)){

    Scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Valor del 1 al 9");
    if ((valor >10)&&(valor <20)){
              System.out.println("Valor del 10 al 19");
if ((valor >= 20)&&(valor<30)){ System.out.println("Valor del 20 al 29");

} }else{ System.out.println("Incorrcete");

} } } }
```

Para que te funcionase debería ser algo así:

```
if(valor>10 $$ valor<10){
   Scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Valor del 1 al 9");
}else if(valor>=10 && valor<20){
    System.out.println("Valor del 10 al 19");
}else{
    System.out.println("Incorrcete");
}
```

Aquí después de cada comprobación mira la otra, nunca se deja ningún if sin comprobar. :)

Comment: Si, he cambiado el codigo y funciona ahora bien.